# Is Windows NT 4.0 Server and Client compatible to newer computer builds?

Tags: virtualization, windows

Our uncle let us fix their HR System (Human Resource System), and we gathered these problems:
(The problems to be presented must be only fixed by automation(computer program))

1. They have a very old hardware (since 1999) for the system, the Server is running Windows NT 4.0 Server and to be able to access it they have a client, Windows NT running in a virtual machine, with HOST OS of windows 98 (since 1999).
2. They have a very old printer (since 1999) attached to the client computer. The model/brand is Kyo Cera. The printer has a parallel connector.

Our real problems are:

1.1 Does Windows NT 4.0 compatible to newer computer builds, so we can just install the OS in there?

1.2 If not, what causes it? Is there a limitation for the OS to be installed?

1.3 Is the printer compatible to newer computer builds together with the client OS?

.

1.4 For illustration purposes of our propose solution:
We may assume that:

we now bought:

-new computer with windows 7 OS

-new printer(usb)
.

.

Is it possible to have/ run properly and smoothly a Windows NT 4.0(client) in a virtual machine like "Virtual Box" with a HOST OS of windows 7?

1.4.1 Can the virtual OS access the windows NT 4.0 Server and read/write data to it?

Can the virtual OS access the new printer and be able to print?
.

.

*we can't find many information regarding this topic many don't exist/deleted.

Comment: Hyper-V does not support Windows NT as a guest OS, and ServerFault does not support homework and research questions.

Comment: thanks and sorry for inconvenience, 
can you elaborate your answer regarding the hyper v?

Comment: If your uncle is also your professor, he should ask for more funds from the department for the infrastructure

Answer (score 5):

This isn't going to work. No modern hardware or hypervisors support NT4. This is a driver/HAL issue and there is no easy way around it. This is why people in your position hoard old junk hardware like the precious.

Comment: The preciousssss

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=software&testConfig=16&productid=10969&releaseid=187&supRel=201,171,187,168,76,196,158,148,24,182,80,74,34,13,31,21,15,12,11,6,84,14,5,2,1,217,155,165,164,163,162,86,85,71,75,70,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,218,199,179,90,89,81,79,78,77,72,48,47,46,&deviceCategory=software&operatingSystems=55&testConfigurations=16&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc&testConfig=16

Comment: Gone in 5.1 however. Well, deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

We currently run NT4 on VMware vSphere 5.1 - although Build 799733 no longer supports NT4. However, this is **not** recommended. Do yourself, and your uncle a favor - update the hardware. Contact the software vendor and get an updated version of their software as well. From personal experience, it's not worth the headache you're about to endure.